# Is there a way to improve Bootstrap accordion performance on tablets and mobiles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, web-applications, accordion, desktop

I'm using bootstrap v3.3.6. In my application the accordion is working properly on desktop but not in the tablet or mobile. Expanding and collapsing panels not smooth.

Is there a way to improve the performance?